# Openbravo: How to save Product in database using rest web services?

Tags: openbravo

I have successfully installed `Openbravo`, Now I am tesing for `web services`. I have successfully created and tested GetProductDetails web service using Restful Web service. Now I am doing save product in database. But it is not working. Below is my code to save product.

```
public void doPut(String path, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // and return something...
        String returnMessage;
        try {
            final SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
            final Document document = reader.read(request.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("##### document : "+document.asXML());
            // create a converter from xml to Openbravo business objects
            final XMLEntityConverter xec = XMLEntityConverter.newInstance();
            System.out.println("Get Client : "+OBContext.getOBContext().getCurrentClient().getName());
            xec.setClient(OBContext.getOBContext().getCurrentClient());
            System.out.println("Get Organization : "+OBContext.getOBContext().getCurrentOrganization().getName());
            xec.setOrganization(OBContext.getOBContext().getCurrentOrganization());

            // for a webservice referenced entities should not be created, see the javadoc
            // for more information
            xec.getEntityResolver().setOptionCreateReferencedIfNotFound(false);

            // process the dom4j document, does the actual conversion
            xec.process(document);

            // list the new objects (which do not yet exist in the db)
            for (BaseOBObject bob : xec.getToInsert()) {
              System.err.println("New business objects: " + bob.getIdentifier());
            }

            // list the objects which will be updated
            for (BaseOBObject bob : xec.getToUpdate()) {
              System.err.println("Updated business objects: " + bob.getIdentifier());
            }

            returnMessage = WebServiceUtil.getInstance().createResultXMLWithObjectsAndWarning(
                "Action performed successfully", "", xec.getWarningMessages(), xec.getToInsert(),
                xec.getToUpdate(), null);
            final Writer w = response.getWriter();
            w.write(returnMessage);
            w.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my simple Product xml data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Openbravo xmlns="http://www.openbravo.com">
<Product>
<description>Test Description</description>
<imageUrl>Test Image URL</imageUrl>
<listPrice>50</listPrice>
<name>Test Name</name>
<number>number</number>
<purchasePrice>50</purchasePrice>
</Product>
</Openbravo>
```

I am not getting any exception nor data is save in database. This is the output I get

```
Output from Server .... 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <ob:result xmlns:ob="http://www.openbravo.com">
      <msg>Action performed successfully</msg>
    </ob:result>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used JSON rest web service. Now successfully added product in the database.